# can't read logger message thru socat -u UNIX-RECV:/dev/log,ignoreeof - because there is no new line

Tags: readline, eof, syslog, socat

I'm trying to simulate syslogd in bash using socat, unfortunately, logger doesn't send a newline to /dev/log after sending a message (it sends eof)

Is there an option to ingnoreeof and convert that in newline (crlf or whatever that makes bash read happy).

I'm trying socat | while read -r LINE do; treat $LINE; done but read blocks because it sees no newline.

Right now, I have a custom logmessage command that displays my messages where I need (console, plymouth special skin, remote syslog, ..), unfortunately, I miss all message that are sent to /dev/log by commands and other stuffs. Using the socat approach to simulate a syslogd on /dev/log would let me grab all messages including important ones (except kmsg which is another story)...

(/dev/log doesn't exists yet (Im in an initrd in cmdline hook)

```
socat UNIX-RECV:/dev/log,ignoreeof STDOUT | while read -r LINE
do
    echo "Parsing $LINE" > /tmp/debug.txt
done&

logger -p local0.info -t systemimager "My test message"
```

doing strace logger and strace socat proves that the message is correctly sent, but the problem is that the read command will never end waiting indefinitely for an eof we ignore otherwise the socat process exits...

(because the read blocks, the debug file stays empty)

if I do:

```
socat UNIX-RECV:/dev/log,ignoreeof CREATE:/tmp/buffer.log&
tail -f /tmp/buffer.log | while read -r LINE
do
    echo "Parsing $LINE" > /tmp/debug.txt
done&

logger -p local0.info -t systemimager "My test message"
```

I have the exact same behavior, though I can see that all messages sent by logger are added to the /tmp/buffer.log file one after another without any newline in between...

Im' in a centos-6 specially crafted initrd (systemimager imager https://github.com/finley/SystemImager/wiki/ScreenShots)

Centos-6 lacks rsylogd in its initrd, so I need to write a minimalistic one that is used in my log dispatcher that will send the messages to console, to plymouth log viewer and to remote xml logger (and eventually to remote syslogd)

(on systemd based system, the journald is running, so I use a journalctl command before my while read -r LINE and of course it works).

I'd like to avoid as much as possible to spawn much processes per log received.

Ideally, when socat receive an EOF, sending a newline instead of quitting would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is capture the debug output from socat, as this includes the number of data bytes received. You can then get the shell to read exactly that number of characters.  For example,

```bash
socat -v -u UNIX-RECV:/dev/log,ignoreeof OPEN:/dev/null 2>&1 |
while read sign date time len from to
do      len=${len##*=}
        read -n "$len" -r LINE
        echo "Parsing $LINE"
done
```

This uses `socat -u` for unidirectional data flow so we can OPEN `/dev/null` as the output file. The `-v` writes debug to stderr which we redirect to the pipe.  Typical output for each input record takes the form of a header line (beginning with `>` and ending `\n`):

```
 > 2019/08/07 21:53:42.951165  length=50 from=0 to=49
```

followed by, in this example, 50 bytes of received data that you need to capture. The `while` loop above reads the header line, splitting the words so that variable `len` will hold the `length=50` string. This is then reduced to leave just the number `50`, and a second read is done with option `-n` which stops the read after that many characters.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. Thanks a lot for sharing.
Too bad that there is no official solution like eof2nl option that would keep connection upon receiving EOF and replace that with a newline in output...